# Image source is wrong Spring

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to show an image which is located in a folder in my Desktop. My problem is this when i set source to image thymeleaf or spring engine appends localhost:8080 to its path.

```
<img alt="" src="/Users/abdullahtellioglu/Desktop/ZambakResimler/yarnartjeans.jpg">
```

This is the image path. I also tried this one.

```
<a href="product_detail.html"><img th:src="@{/Users/abdullahtellioglu/Desktop/ZambakResimler/yarnartjeans.jpg}" alt="" /></a>
```

Both of them gives me the following path.

```
http://localhost:8080/Users/abdullahtellioglu/Desktop/ZambakResimler/yarnartjeans.jpg
```

I am not sure how to remove localhost:8080 from path and make the path absolute.

Comment: The desktop is not the right place to get an image you want to use in a Spring app. You better put your images in some *resource* folder

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing is not how a server should works. When you want to make available some resource from your webapp you need to it to your web app resources. Here is a brief example of how could you fix it.

1. Go to the folder `src/main/resources` and create a folder called `static`.
2. Under that folder create another one called `img` and inside copy your image. So we would have something like this now:

   ```
   src
      main
          resources
                  static
                       img
                          yarnartjeans.jpg.jpg
   ```
3. Now go to your thymeleaf HTML page and use this

   ```
   <a href="product_detail.html">
       <img th:src="@{/img/yarnartjeans.jpg}" alt=""/>
   </a>
   ```

Now your HTML page will load your image correctly

Good luck